# Concurrent processing of single InputStream with independent consumers

Tags: java, concurrency, stream, inputstream

I need to spawn N consumer threads, which process same InputStream concurrently, e.g - transform it somehow, calculate checksum or digital signature etc. These consumers do not depend on each other and all of them are using third-party libraries, which accept InputStream as source of data.

So what I can do is - create some implementation of InputStream, which will

- read chunk of data from "parent" stream
- unblock consumers
- wait until every consumer read the whole chunk
- read next chunk

while being looking simple, it may rise various problems like livelock when certain consumer dies, implement all of InputStream methods, control fork/join of consumers themselves using barriers/latches etc.

One buddy told me that it's half of an hour to implement, it made my evening.

I'd prefer either use something mature enough (googling didn't come with results thus, my google-fu isn't good enough?) or don't bother and copy entire "source" stream into a temporary file and use it as source of data. The latter solution seems to be more reliable, but may end up in creation of gigabyte files (when processing streaming audio for example).

Comment: Can you write the data to a file and spawn N FileInputStreams?

Comment: @JonLin As he said towards the end of the question, he can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, you should have at least some kind of buffering so different consumers can move through the stream at different pace without everything being constantly bogged down by the currently slowest consumer. That basically ensures worst-case performance and very little benefit of concurrency.

You could, say, tag each chunk with the consumers that have used it so far and then delete those that are completely used up. Maybe this could be achieved by each consumer holding a reference to each chunk it hasn't yet used, which would allow GC to automatically take care of used chunks. The producer might keep a list of `WeakReference`s to the chunks so it has a handle on the number of chunks yet to be used and base its throttling on that.

I am also thinking about having a separate `InputStream` instance per thread, which internally communicates with the producer `InputStream`. This way you have an easy solution for your livelock hazard: `try ... finally { is.close(); }` -- the dying consumer closes its own inputstream. This is communicated to the producer.

I have some ideas with using an `ArrayBlockingQueue` per consumer. There would be some difficulty in ensuring that all consumers are properly fed, without making the producer either block or busy-wait.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is very little benefit - having 5 consumers working for 1 secons and one consumer working for 2 seconds, concurrent invocation will give 2 seconds while sequential will give 7 seconds. Or am I missing something here? With having  tagged chunks and buffers I will hit memory consumption, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Yes, what you say is inescapable. However, if you have consumers balanced on average, but their performance widely varying, you'll lose the opportunity for concurrence if you always wait for each consumer that currently lags behind. Buffering would help there. And if you introduce thread priority balancing, you could actually achieve such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using pipe streams? Your producer can have a one or more [PipedOuputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) in which it throws whatever it reads from the file. At the other side of the pipes, you have different consumer threads reading on a corresponding [PipedInputstream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) (which is an InputStream that you can share with your libraries).

Your producer thread can decide through which of the pipes data should be sent, by means of this, providing data to be processed for a given consumer thread reading on the other side of the pipe.

If you need to get data back from your consumer threads, then you can create another pipe, in the opposite direction, to send the data back to you.

Comment: A `PipedOutputStream` will block the producer as soon as any consumer lags behind, starving all other consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some Java Messaging Service (JMS) implementation like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

In your case you'd need to create a so called *Topic* (see [Topics vs. Queues](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)). A topic is created by the producer, and is published to N consumers, which may run concurrently, with each consumer receiving exactly the same data.

Since you want to use `InputStream`s there is a chapter on how to [send messages are streams](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-streams.html).

I suppose, typically, producers and consumers would be separate processes, probably running on different machines on the network. I think you can configure it to run completely in a single JVM, though. This would depend on the implementation of JMS. These are also quite famous: [HornetQ by JBoss](https://www.jboss.org/hornetq), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), and a whole bunch of others.