# how to read bitmap and meta-data from a png stream/file efficiently?

Tags: image, bitmap, png, metadata

I need to decode both bitmap and meta data from PNG input stream using [PNGJ] (http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library. The problem is that decoding meta data will advance the stream and then I cannot use 
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

Creating Bitmap on my own is OK but if I need to, say, scale bitmap with interpolation I'd rather  use BitmapFactory. To use it I have to create a copy of InputStream every time I have to use PNGJ for getting meta data and BitmapFactory for getting a bitmap. It will be nice to return meta data AND Bitmap from a single PNGJ call (at least for most common ARGB_8888 format).

In a nutshell, I have to copy the stream to be used by Java libraries which looks like a waste. Returning a bitmap will be one solution.

```
    // register an auxilary chunk name 
    PngChunk.factoryRegister(ThumbNailProvider.chunkID, chunkPROP.class); 

    // reader for the stream
    PngReader pngr = new PngReader(inStream, "debug label PNG reader");
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PngWriter pngw = new PngWriter(outputStream, pngr.imgInfo);

    // copy pre-data chunks
    pngw.copyChunksFirst(pngr, ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE);

    // copy image data
    for (int row = 0; row < pngr.imgInfo.rows; row++) {
        ImageLine l1 = pngr.readRow(row);
        pngw.writeRow(l1, row);
    }

    // copy after-data chunks
    pngw.copyChunksLast(pngr, ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL); 

    pngr.end(); // close inStream but not its copy
    pngw.end(); // close out stream

    // save a copy of the stream for Java Libraries;
    data.inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());



    // read the chunk
    ChunksList chunkList = pngr.getChunksList();
    PngChunk chunk = chunkList.getById1(L2ThumbNailProvider.chunkID);
    if (chunk != null) {
    ... 
    }
```

Comment: If you want help optimizing your code, post your code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of having two independent streams consumers, say `Class1.parse(inputStream)`, `Class2.decode(inputStream)` and we want them to consume the same single stream; it has no simple elegant solutions ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334963/concurrent-processing-of-single-inputstream-with-independent-consumers)), if we have no control on how the consumers eat the stream.

Simple solutions, but not very elegant -and probably impractical- are: close and reopen the stream (unfeasible if we are reading from a network stream), buffer the full stream content in memory, or to a temporary file.

In your concrete case, the alternatives I can think of are:

1) Let PNGJ consume and decode the data and create the Bitmap yourself, filling the pixels it with [setPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). This, among other inconveniences, would require you to do the proper color conversions.

2) Use PngReader as a InputFilterStream, so that it only parses the metadata and pass the full stream to the consumer. Currently, this is not possible, withouth tweaking on the PNGJ code. I will give it a look, and if a implement this feature I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instrumental answer. InputFilterStream will work only if we store our meta data before bitmap data, right? I also can rewind a stream a bit using mark()/reset() functions. Currently, I either make a copy of the stream (which is not very efficient) or cast it into InputFilterStream which position is not moved after BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor() is called:             FileInputStream fs = (FileInputStream) mIS;
        java.io.FileDescriptor fd = fs.getFD()

Comment: Sorry, what I meat was this: InputFilterStream will work only if we store our meta data before bitmap data, right? I also can rewind a stream a bit using mark()/reset() functions. Currently, I either make a copy of the stream (which is not very efficient) or cast it into file descriptor which position is not moved after BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor() is called:             FileInputStream fs = (FileInputStream) mIS;
        java.io.FileDescriptor fd = fs.getFD()

Comment: If  your stream comes from a file, then why not just open it twice? Seems the most simple and efficient way, specially if you want PngJ just to parse the metadata. Bear in mind that PngReader has a [readSkippingAllRows()](http://goo.gl/O7IR6) method that is very efficient for that scenario.

Comment: no it doesn't come from a file but from the server. FileDescriptor solution allows to read stream non destructively though.